# How do I get the URL of the image returned by the Wolfram API?

Tags: image, wolframalpha

I'm using the Wolfram Simple API and it generates an image as a result. I want to show that image in an imageview but the problem is that I can't get the url of the image.I searched a lot but couldn't find anything.Can anybody help me and guide how do I get the url of the result image?

Comment: Wolfram Simple API returns image, not the image url. So, you will have to pass the received to image source directly.

Comment: @abhijeetchimankar could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to find Natalie Portman's picture via wolframalpha:

```
http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?appid=DEMO&input=natalie%20portman&includepodid=Image:PeopleData&output=json
```

This request specifically requests just the Image pod be returned (via JSON).

Result:

```
{
    "queryresult": {
        "success": true,
        "error": false,
        "numpods": 1,
        "datatypes": "People",
        "timedout": "",
        "timedoutpods": "",
        "timing": 1.489,
        "parsetiming": 0.139,
        "parsetimedout": false,
        "recalculate": "",
        "id": "MSP",
        "host": "http://www5a.wolframalpha.com",
        "server": "40",
        "related": "http://www5a.wolframalpha.com",
        "version": "2.6",
        "pods": [
            {
                "title": "Image",
                "scanner": "Data",
                "id": "Image:PeopleData",
                "position": 100,
                "error": false,
                "numsubpods": 1,
                "subpods": [
                    {
                        "title": "",
                        "imagesource": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Natalie_Portman_at_TIFF_2009.jpg",
                        "img": {
                            "src": "http://www5a.wolframalpha.com",
                            "alt": "",
                            "title": "",
                            "width": 101,
                            "height": 150
                        },
                        "plaintext": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "sources": {
            "url": "http://www.wolframalpha.com/sources/PeopleDataSourceInformationNotes.html",
            "text": "People data"
        }
    }
}
```

To get at the URL using python for example:

```
image_url = json_result['queryresult']['pods'][0]['subpods'][0]['imagesource']
print(image_url)
```

image_url:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Natalie_Portman_at_TIFF_2009.jpg
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Natalie_Portman_at_TIFF_2009.jpg

Comment: actually I'm using it for calculating equation , so what should I pass in `includepodid` ?

Comment: For this query: http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?input=\int_0^5 x^2 dx if you check the json result, the graph is returned in the pod id: "VisualRepresentationOfTheIntegral".

Comment: I'm using this query : http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?appid=DEMO&i=(2x-3=5)   and I get an image in response ,where do I check the json result ?

Answer (score 0):

For Wolfram Simple API, you have to pass the url output directly to image.

`http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?appid=DEMO&i=What+airplanes+are+flying+overhead%3F`

You can refer to working sample here:

```js
var url = 'http://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/simple?appid=DEMO&i=What+airplanes+are+flying+overhead%3F';

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
    url : url, 
}).always(function(){
    $("#IMAGE_ID").attr("src", url);
    
}); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <img id='IMAGE_ID'>
</body>
```